# How to move the cursor to a specific position in a specific line in ScintillaNet control?

Tags: c#, .net, scintilla

I need to move the cursor to a desired position of a certain line by code, any ideas which could get that to work will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

> **SCI_GOTOLINE(int line)** This removes any selection and sets the caret at the start of line number line and scrolls the view (if
>   needed) to make it visible. The anchor position is set the same as the
>   current position. If line is outside the lines in the document (first
>   line is 0), the line set is the first or last.

Taken from http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html

Comment: Actually I was able to get it done this way: `scintilla1.GoTo.Line(2);
int nowPosition = scintilla1.Caret.Position;
int wantedPosition = nowPosition + 3;
scintilla1.GoTo.Position(wantedPosition);
scintilla1.Focus();`
Thanks!