# Scintilla .NET editor. Position cursor at the first visible line

Tags: c#, .net, scintilla

I am using the Scintilla .NET text editor control (ScintillaNet.dll) to display SQL. I am using the following command to position the caret cursor at a given line number. In the example below, I am positioning the caret cursor at line 102 (0 based. The grid displays 1-based line numbers.)

```
scintilla1.GoTo.Line(102); //0 based
```

[image: What I get]

I'd like text in the viewport to be displayed at the top of the screen as shown below, as the first visible line

[image: What I want]

How can I identify how to do this?

### Update

This looked promising:

```
scintilla1.Lines.FirstVisible.Number = targetLineNumber;
```

but after executing, `scintilla1.Lines.FirstVisible.Number` wasn't always equal to `targetLineNumber` and I don't know what is interfering with it.There are hundreds of lines following the `targetLineNumber` line.

Comment: Take a look at this answer. Hopefully, that will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675217/how-to-move-the-cursor-to-a-specific-position-in-a-specific-line-in-scintillanet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get/Set first visible line works for me https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETFIRSTVISIBLELINE

You can keep the cursor position first (SCI_GOTOPOS) and then set the first visible line